# Shift Tab on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Using the command "Shift-Tab" does not work in Google Colab.  Does anyone know an alternative that can be used?

I tried using shift + tab during the command and after a parenthesis after the command.  For example, it was used at "print" and then again at "print("

Comment: What is it that you expect Shift-Tab to do? Autocomplete? If so, that's control-space (or command-space on osx)

Answer (score 18):

On Colab, for <kbd>SHIFT+ TAB</kbd> to work, you have to disable `Automatically trigger code completions` on `Tools->Settings`.

You also have to have already imported the library that you are trying to get the docstring. For example run the `import` in another code snippet.

All Shortcuts can be found using <kbd>CTRL + M</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> or going to `Tools->Keyboard Shortcuts`

Answer (score 5):

Add a `?` character and run the cell. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can see the docstring also just pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> on Colab.

e.g.: `print( + TAB`

If it doesn't work, disable the `Automatically trigger code completions` by going to `Tools->Settings->Editor`

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut for showing the docstring on Colab is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>